# Use of a Sennheiser EW 100 ENG G3-A in China

Tags: microphone, wireless, sennheiser, lapel, radio-frequency

I am travelling to China (Sichuan and Yunnan) and planning to use a Sennheiser EW 100 ENG G3-A Wireless Lapel Microphone System - bought in Australia. I would like to know:

- whether the use of wireless microphones is allowed
- "A" frequency band (516-558 MHz) is suitable for those regions

Comment: have you checked http://www.frequencyfinder.eu/ ?

Comment: I tried to search for Chengdu city and it finds it on the map but there is no information related to the frequencies.

Comment: Ah i see, there's no information available.. So I guess your best bet is trying http://jwsoundgroup.net/ and ask for experience by recordist. I've only done sfx recording in china so no wireless systems.. However I did record with DPA 4060's.